# How to properly format a raw DNS query?

Tags: dns, network-programming

I'm creating a Lua library to help process sending and receiving DNS requests and am currently reading [this](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) (DNS protocol RFC), but I'm unaware of how to properly format the request. For instance, do I have to specify how long the message? How do I do this?

I understand, from my Wireshark inspection, that I'm supposed to also include options afterwards. I also see a `0x00` in the response; does this mean that I just simply have to zero-terminate the request name before adding in values?

The section I'm specifically talking about is 4.1.3 of the RFC.

Some notes: I tested this with a personal server and got these values in the query section: `06 61 6c 69 73 73 61 04 69 6e 66 6f 00`. The `00` in particular is what interests me, it's highlighted in WireShark, which means it's significant. I assume it means that the values are null-terminated? Then the options about the type and class follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When section 4.1.3 refers to a "NAME", it's referring back to the definition in section 3.1, which specifies that a domain name consists of a sequence of labels, each of which consist of a length specification octet and a number of octets. The final label is always the root zone, which has a zero-length name and thus consists only of a length octet with a zero in it. So, yes, the whole name is terminated with a zero octet, but it's not "zero-terminated" in the usual C string sense.

Note also that only the lower six bits in the length octets are the length data, the uppermost two bits are flags.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading through the spec and I saw the note about the two flags but I couldn't remember what section it was for. This helped clear things up; I didn't entirely understand 3.1 when I was reading it at the time. Thanks again. This'll definitely help.

I suppose I can just use size & ~(2^7+2^6) to get rid of those first two leading bits and get the size.

Comment: @AlissaSquared - This guy gave you a good answer, why not accept it?

Comment: Sorry about that, I must've fixed it in the meantime and not get the notification email. Yes, this was a working solution.